# Jquery Mobile UI styles in android layout without WebView

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile styles is a contrasted look and a royal interface to impressive the users, when i am implemented those methods in webview of android its look perfect, so by what way shall i implement in normal android layout itself without the interface of webview to get the same style? i needed the styles of listview in Jquery Mobile to my android layouts without Webview.

Helps appreciated.!